# Cannot read XML file in Google Map V3

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Map api v3. I am trying to create a dynamic web project in Java EE. For this, I want to show some places(marker) in the google map. To do that java script must read from XML file. I have found some example here. 
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/

It looks fine but when I have downloaded the files in my computer (downloadurl.html, data.xml) and opened it using chrome/firefox, the map is visible but the markers is not. It looks to me that it has failed to read from XML file.

Could you please give me advise where is the problem and how to fix it? My files are here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B64N8GK8re42aGd5OUNXeXpIbWM

Thank you.

Comment: A few things may help us help you. 1. A live link to your map.2. Any error messages.3. Add code(EDIT) to your question. One possible answer is badly formed XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must download util.js too and run downloadurl.html on a webserver(util.js loads the xml using XMLHttpRequest, which doesn't work in chrome/FF on local filesystem )